# Change color when form changes

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form with multiple textboxes inside a table.
Also inside the table but outside the form there is a cell (said Cell A).

When you first access the form, texboxes in the form are filled with data from a DataBase using php/MySQL.

You can change the textbox values, and submit them to the database with POST. The Database is updated, and you are returned to the same (but now updated) form.

My issue: I want to appear in Cell A a colored text indicating if the data in the form was sent or not. On first arrival to the page or after update in should read "Actualized data" in green. But when you are changing the form without submitting it should change to "Unsent data" in red (or something like that).

I know how to format the text with php

```
style="color:<?php echo $ColorChange ?>"
```

but when the form changes (before submitting) I need OnChange and some JavaScript, for example

```
function ChangeColor()
{
var col=document.getElementById("UpdateSign");
col.style.color="#FF0000";
}
```

My problem is how to combine those two. Any ideas?

Comment: Your first problem is the fact Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: So add change events to all your form elements.

Comment: Thanks epascarello. Adding change events to all form elements worked. And i drop my original (and bad) idea of sending formats through php. Also need some reading regarding Java & JavaScript (I'm a biologist indeed...)

Comment: update: i still send formats and text through php. It works, and reassures me that data is comming from server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Keep Javascript event triggers outside of HTML elements, and use event listeners.  jQuery makes binding event listeners to elements very easy.

For example,

```
$("#form_input_element").on("onchange", ChangeColor);
```

takes in the id of the form element and binds the `ChangeColor` function to the `onchange` event.

Answer (score -3):

use the onchange event of the body, i suppose this should work. I dont know your complete code so this is more guessing than knowing.

```
<body onchange=ChangeColor()>
```